# Qt Ctrl++ (Control Plus Plus) Shortcut Not Working in Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator, dispatch

I've noticed in Qt 5.5.0 and in Qt Creator 3.4.2 (built on Qt 5.5.0), that Actions attempting to use Ctrl++ are not working.  Note that the shortcut works correctly in older versions (for example, Qt Creator 2.7.0 built on Qt 5.0.2).

For example, if I try to increase the font size in QtCreator using Ctrl++, nothing happens.    The same is true for the ImageViewer example.  (Ctrl++ in the ImageViewer increases the image size, but in 5.5.0, it does not work.)

If I bind increasing the font size to another shortcut in QtCreator (via Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard), such as Ctrl+Z, it works fine.

I did a little debug by overriding keyPressEvent, and it appears that Ctrl++ is being sucked up earlier in the dispatch, but I am having trouble figuring out exactly where.

My questions are:

1. Is this a bug?
2. If not, does anyone have any advice on how to see how the key is being dispatched?

Comment: Are you actually pressing Ctrl - Plus? The + / = key sends `=` if you don't press shift, so if you're pressing Ctrl and the + / = key, that's actually sending Ctrl - Equals.

Comment: Yes, I am pressing the correct sequence.   It works in older versions of Qt.

Comment: I have the same thing on my Windows version. QtCreator V3.4.2 based on Qt 5.5.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit).  Crtl --  works, though.  I now have tiny text in my editor window :/   Ctrl++ works in my older version I have on a Linux box.

Comment: Just as an additional datapoint: command++ (the ctrl++ equivalent on mac) works fine for me on OS X, QtC 3.4.2/5.5.0, from the official installer. If you can’t use those shortcut, that sounds like a QtCreator bug to me and you should report it.

Comment: I reported it and it was confirmed as a bug.   Note that it was a qt_base bug that manifested itself in anything built on qt 5.5.0 (including QtCreator).

Answer (score 2):

This is a confirmed bug in Qt 5.5.0 and appears to be fixed in the latest builds.

There is more information here:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47701